# How to get input through submit button then printed as text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

First of all sorry for bad code, I'm a noob! However, I'm tinkering with some tkinter, and I almost reached my goal with the code... But I can't seem to figure out how to get the input from input fields converted to the text box when the button is pushed.

The code seems to work, as I'm getting the desired output in my terminal, just not in the tkinter window. I have tried with a normal text box and scrolledtext.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

fields = ('Principal', 'Expected Return', 'Number of Years', 'Yearly Payment', 'Cost Rate') #fields for gui

def some_logics(entry_from_user):
    #grab input from user from fields
    principal = int(entry_from_user['Principal'].get()) 
    rate_return = float(entry_from_user['Expected Return'].get()) /100
    number_periods = int(entry_from_user['Number of Years'].get())
    pmt = int(entry_from_user['Yearly Payment'].get())
    rate_cost = float(entry_from_user['Cost Rate'].get()) /100

    #main function, utilizes variables to calculcate and print out desired text
    def print_out():

        #investment return, initial investment, expected yearly return, number of years, yearly payment
        def accrued(principal, rate_return, number_periods, pmt=0):
            cash = principal
            for periods in range(number_periods):
                cash += (cash * rate_return) + pmt
            return cash

        #if capital is borrowed insert capital, cost of capital and number of years
        def cost_of_capital(principal, rate_cost, number_periods):
            effective_cost_rate = (1 + (rate_cost/12))**12 - 1
            return principal * effective_cost_rate * number_periods


        end_cash = accrued(principal, rate_return, number_periods, pmt) #calculate total end sum for investment
        cost_capital_end = cost_of_capital(principal, rate_cost, number_periods) #calculate total cost of capital
        print(end_cash)
        print(cost_capital_end)
        print(f'Initial investment was {principal}, while after the period cash is {end_cash}. This is a total gain of {end_cash - principal}')
        print(f'Of the total gain {pmt * number_periods} was coming from the installments. This results in a net gain of {end_cash - principal - (pmt * number_periods)}')
        print(f'Cost of investment is: {cost_capital_end} and this shows a actual gain of {(end_cash - principal - (pmt * number_periods)) - cost_capital_end}')

    return print_out()

def makeform(root, fields):
    #create a dictionary for fields
    entries = {} 
    for field in fields:
        print(field)
        row = tk.Frame(root)
        lab = tk.Label(row, width=22, text=field+": ", anchor='w')
        ent = tk.Entry(row)
        ent.insert(0, "0")
        row.pack(side = tk.TOP, fill = tk.X, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        lab.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
        ent.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, expand = tk.YES, fill = tk.X)
        entries[field] = ent
    return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk() #initialize object
    ents = makeform(root, fields) #create form
    #create a button, button is placing user input into funcion
    b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Calculate',
        command = (lambda e=ents: some_logics(e)))
    b1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    #create a quit program button
    b2 = tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
    b2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
    #create a textfield which returns user input in format from print_out function
    T = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, state='disabled')
    T.pack(side= tk.BOTTOM, padx=5, pady=5)
    T.insert(tk.END, (lambda e=ents: some_logics(e)))
    root.mainloop()
```

Bonus Questions: I restructed the code to nested functions, is this pythonic or just noise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the nested functions are noisy, yes.

The changes I did here are:

- autoformatting with Black
- wrapping the main logic in a `main()` function to avoid using globals
- un-nesting the nested functions into free functions (these would belong in a module really)
- refactoring the output-generating function into a free function
- making the `update_form` (née `some_logics`) function accept the output field it should update (and actually update it)
- fixing the slightly unorthodox use of lambdas

Hope this helps.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

fields = (
    "Principal",
    "Expected Return",
    "Number of Years",
    "Yearly Payment",
    "Cost Rate",
)  # fields for gui


# investment return, initial investment, expected yearly return, number of years, yearly payment
def accrued(principal, rate_return, number_periods, pmt=0):
    cash = principal
    for periods in range(number_periods):
        cash += (cash * rate_return) + pmt
    return cash


# if capital is borrowed insert capital, cost of capital and number of years
def cost_of_capital(principal, rate_cost, number_periods):
    effective_cost_rate = (1 + (rate_cost / 12)) ** 12 - 1
    return principal * effective_cost_rate * number_periods


def calculate_output(number_periods, pmt, principal, rate_cost, rate_return):
    end_cash = accrued(
        principal, rate_return, number_periods, pmt
    )  # calculate total end sum for investment
    cost_capital_end = cost_of_capital(
        principal, rate_cost, number_periods
    )  # calculate total cost of capital
    output = "\n".join(
        (
            f"Initial investment was {principal}, while after the period cash is {end_cash}. This is a total gain of {end_cash - principal}",
            f"Of the total gain {pmt * number_periods} was coming from the installments. This results in a net gain of {end_cash - principal - (pmt * number_periods)}",
            f"Cost of investment is: {cost_capital_end} and this shows a actual gain of {(end_cash - principal - (pmt * number_periods)) - cost_capital_end}",
        )
    )
    return output


def update_form(entry_from_user, output_field):
    # grab input from user from fields
    principal = int(entry_from_user["Principal"].get())
    rate_return = float(entry_from_user["Expected Return"].get()) / 100
    number_periods = int(entry_from_user["Number of Years"].get())
    pmt = int(entry_from_user["Yearly Payment"].get())
    rate_cost = float(entry_from_user["Cost Rate"].get()) / 100

    output = calculate_output(number_periods, pmt, principal, rate_cost, rate_return)
    output_field.delete("1.0", tk.END)  # clear
    output_field.insert(tk.INSERT, output)


def makeform(root, fields):
    # create a dictionary for fields
    entries = {}
    for field in fields:
        row = tk.Frame(root)
        lab = tk.Label(row, width=22, text=field + ": ", anchor="w")
        ent = tk.Entry(row)
        ent.insert(0, "0")
        row.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=5)
        lab.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        ent.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.X)
        entries[field] = ent
    return entries


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()  # initialize object

    output_field = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root)  # create output field

    ents = makeform(root, fields)  # create form
    # create a button, button is placing user input into funcion
    b1 = tk.Button(
        root, text="Calculate", command=lambda: update_form(ents, output_field)
    )
    b1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    # create a quit program button
    b2 = tk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.quit)
    b2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
    # create a textfield which returns user input in format from print_out function
    output_field.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, padx=5, pady=5)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful! Will also stop with the nested functions, bad habit from Excel I guess.

Comment: Glad I could help. One good reason for not having nested functions is easier unit testability, too, once you get to writing tests.